# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()/ select subset from data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

My input file is under the form:

```
    gold,Program,MethodType,CallersT,CallersN,CallersU,CallersCallersT,CallersCallersN,CallersCallersU,CalleesT,CalleesN,CalleesU,CalleesCalleesT,CalleesCalleesN,CalleesCalleesU,CompleteCallersCallees,classGold
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,Medium,High,-1,High,0,Trace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,Medium,High,-1,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Medium,-1,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,0,NoTrace,
T,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Low,Low,Medium,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,0,NoTrace,
....
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,NoTrace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,Low,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,Trace,
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,-1,Low,Low,-1,-1,-1,0,NoTrace,
```

and I would like to select rows that either have the values for (`CallersU` equal to either `Low` OR `-1`) AND the values of (`CalleesU` equal either to `Low` OR `-1`).

Here is the code I am using below:

```
import pandas as pd
SeparateProjectLearning=False
CompleteCallersCallees=False
PartialTrainingSetCompleteCallersCallees=True
def main():
  
    dataset = pd.read_csv( 'InputData.txt', sep= ',', index_col=False) 
    #convert strings into 1 and N into 0
    dataset['gold'] = dataset['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['Program'] = dataset['Program'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['classGold'] = dataset['classGold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes 
    dataset['CallersT'] = dataset['CallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersN'] = dataset['CallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersU'] = dataset['CallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersT'] = dataset['CallersCallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersN'] = dataset['CallersCallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersU'] = dataset['CallersCallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    
    
    print(dataset)
    CompleteSet =  dataset[(dataset['CallersU']==0 or dataset['CallersU']==2)
                               and (dataset['CalleesU']==0 or dataset['CalleesU']==2)]  

    print(CompleteSet)    

if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

I am using the line `dataset['CallersU'] = dataset['CallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes` to convert the string values that can be taken by `CallersU` into digits. Similarly, I am using the line of code       `dataset['CalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes` to convert the string values that can be taken by `CalleesU` into digits. The four values that can be taken by `CallersU/CalleesU` are -1, `Low`,`Medium`,`High`. The line `...astype('category').cat.codes` automatically makes the following conversions. -1 corresponds to `0`, 1 Corresponds to `High`, 2 corresponds to `Low` and 3 corresponds to `Medium`. Thus, I am using the line `CompleteSet =  dataset[(dataset['CallersU']==0 or dataset['CallersU']==2) and (dataset['CalleesU']==0 or dataset['CalleesU']==2)]` to specify that I only want to select rows with either `(CallersU==0 OR CallersU==2) and  (CalleesU==0 OR CalleesU==2)`, the problem is that I am getting the error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` after executing the line of code `CompleteSet =  dataset[(dataset['CallersU']==0 or dataset['CallersU']==2) and (dataset['CalleesU']==0 or dataset['CalleesU']==2)]`, How can I fix that and perform what's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `and` with `&` and add ()

```
CompleteSet = dataset[((dataset['CallersU'] == 0) | (dataset['CallersU'] == 2)) & ((dataset['CalleesU']==0) | (dataset['CalleesU']==2))]
```

Comment: I tried it and it's not working, still getting the same error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Sorry o missed the or. Replace or with |

Comment: same error still happens when replacing the or with |

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you implement and check once again?

Comment: wrote down your edited answer and I still get the same error, you can run the program yourself, I am using Spyder IDE and here is a link to the input file InputData.txt so you can run it yourself and check https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vF4ZAPSps_aO2Umsp2hEgK7UxwcXLiZR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok.. let me check

Comment: Done. Answer edited. It worked.

Comment: true it worked for me as well thanks